# Parse a SSE event stream data

Tags: php, server-sent-events

Below is the sample server sent streaming data

```
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:02Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:07Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:12Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:17Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:22Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:27Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:32Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:37Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:42Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:47Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:52Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:23:57Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:24:02Z"}

event:poke
data:{"members":{"count":1,"max":3},"stream":"64fef9129831d40001a72c9b","ts":"2023-09-12T06:24:07Z"}

event:data
data:{"checksum":"5da636f91630e8be3ddc9626cdd8a739","created_at":"2023-09-12T06:24:06.811Z","deleted_at":null,"end_time":"2023-09-12T06:24:03Z","id":"2a70a79861727960772c7e3142119de0","log_id":"55658dc9-7209-4989-abb8-bba35a5ca29c","metrics":[{"origin":"device","type":"body_weight","unit":"kg","value":58}],"offset_origin":"source","source":{"device":{"diagnostics":[{"type":"mobile_device_manufacturer","unit":"n/a","value":"vivo"},{"type":"mobile_device_model_number","unit":"n/a","value":"V2029"},{"type":"operating_system","unit":"n/a","value":"Android"},{"type":"operating_system_version","unit":"n/a","value":"12"},{"type":"validic_library_version","unit":"n/a","value":"1.14.9"}],"id":5000,"manufacturer":"other","model":"weight scale"},"type":"bluetooth"},"start_time":"2023-09-12T06:24:03Z","tags":[],"type":"measurement","user":{"organization_id":"648b22b30b40ba000e13a908","uid":"mobile_demo_for_backend","user_id":"64e6e18761e685000eb6dec2"},"user_notes":[],"utc_offset":19800,"version":"1.0"}
```

This is a continuous stream . I need to parse this data  using PHP and store in backend. I tried using the following code

```
if ($stream = fopen('https://streams.v2.validic.com/streams/6490f9129831d40001a72c9b/connect?token=9dfa7bda8ea3fcecacbaf75473f450991a', 'r')) {
       
        echo stream_get_contents($stream, -1, 0);
    
       
    }
```

This opens the stream but nothing is being printed. Request your valuable suggestions to parse the stream and should I be using a SSE library . If yes then could you suggest me a PHP SSE library?

Comment: Try something ready-made like https://github.com/obsh/sse-client